# Remove heading from Superfish Menu Drupal 7

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm working with Drupal for the first time, and have been able to find answers for all of my other questions, so far, on either Drupal's forms or via other means.  However, I can't seem to find a way to remove the "Main Menu" header from my superfish menu.

I've created a region called superfish and added superfish to it successfully.  But above the menu there is an

### Main Menu

that I would like to remove.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this from the superfish options, and i can't seem to find where in the code this is being appended, or else I would just comment out that line.  I've searched in the `superfish.js` file as well as the 'superfish.module` file and can't seem to find it.  I'm a programmer first and a 'web designer' second, so getting my hands dirty in some code is not a problem, in fact, I would prefer to do it that way.

Has anyone else done this? Or know where I should start to look?

This is the html that is generated at runtime:

```
<div id="superfish">
    <div class="region region-superfish">
        <div id="block-superfish-1" class="block block-superfish contextual-links-region">
        <h2>Main menu</h2>
        <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
            <div class="content">
                <ul id="superfish-1" class="menu sf-menu sf-main-menu sf-horizontal sf-style-simple sf-total-items-2 sf-parent-items-1 sf-single-items-1 superfish-processed sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
                <li id="menu-221-1" class="active-trail first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">
                <li id="menu-312-1" class="active-trail last even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-1 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-1 menuparent">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: +1 because the answer doesn't seem readily available. I'd like to get an answer to the actual location of this text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across the real answer...  Isn't it funny that one tends to figure things out when they stop thinking about them?

The `main menu` header was the block title, when editing the superfish block the very first field is `Block Title` this allows one to override the default setting of the block title.  By placing `<none>` in this field, the block title is no longer displayed.

Comment: I have set Block title as <none> but tittle appear <none>

Answer (score 1):

Apart from finding where that HTML is output, which is the ideal solution, you could use jquery after the fact to remove the title.

```
$('#superfish h2').html('');
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DetEb/

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about solving it after the fact, but yeah, that'll work!

Comment: Cool, it's actually surprising how little info is available with a Google search on this issue. You'd think this would be a common issue. Please accept my answer if it was helpful to you.